# Computing differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to use Leibniz's rule for differentiation under the integral sign for the following problem:

$I_n(x)=\int_{a}^{x} (x-t)^{n-1}f(t)dt$

The answer should be $(n-1)f(x)$ but I got a totally different one, may someone guide me through this?

**According to wikipedia** if we declare $f(x,t)=(x-t)^{n-1}f(t)$ then the differentiation result is:

$f(x,x)+\int_{a}^{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t) dt=\int_{a}^{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t) dt=\int_{a}^{x} (n-1)(x-t)^{n-2}f(t) dt$

What is my mistake?

Comment: If the answer is $(n-1)f(x)$, what is the question? And, btw, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I'm asking for the steps to learn since I got another answer...

Comment: please wait until I publish more details in 2 min

Comment: $(n-1) f(x)$ looks wrong. What result did you get?

Comment: Done I have posted my steps, (It's really hard to write math here)

Comment: Your result is correct (for $n \ge 2$).

Comment: how may I continue from here (How to calculate the integral)